# Configuring email from address in Jira 4.1 email notification

Tags: email, notifications, jira

I am trying to configure Jira from email section of email notification. I need to add assignee fullname and status of the issue in the from section.
If anyone knows how to accomplish this task please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIRA deliberately sends email from one address so that replies can have their text added as comments. If you sent email as the actual assignee then email would go only to that person, making JIRA less useful as a shared tool.

~Matt